# Sorting Array of string using Comparator (Specific sorting case)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have the following string Array in Java

Input String

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("01", "1", "2", "001", "002", "3", "6", "06", "006", "0001", "7");
```

Expected Output

```
{"0001","001", "01", "1", "002", "2", "3", "006", "06", "6", "7"}
```

What is the correct implementation of the comparator. I have the following algorithmic implementation but I suspect this will not work using values "001" more than than two characters:

```
Arrays.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            Integer position = 0;
            
            char[] firstArray = o1.toCharArray();
            char[] secondArray = o2.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
                if (firstArray[i] != secondArray[i]) {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
     }
 return Integer.valueOf(o1.charAt(position)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.charAt(o2.length() - 1)));
   }
 });
```

This produces the following output and it seems that zero is taking a higher presence.

Actual Output

```
[0001, 001, 002, 006, 01, 06, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you suspect it will not work? Have you tested your code? If you have, does it work? If it doesn't, how does its output differ from the expected output? If you haven't tested your code, you should do that before posting a question, because it might just work. And if it doesn't, you'll see what exactly doesn't work and you'll be able to post a more specific question, with more information that will be required to help you.

Comment: Apologies I have amended the question, I did do a test using my implementation, forgot to include the answer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Arrays.sort` does not compile because `list` is a collection, so `Collections.sort(list, customComparator)` or just `list.sort(customComparator)` should be used instead.

Second, the result of sorting with current comparator implementation is:

```
[0001, 001, 002, 006, 01, 06, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

That is, the entries are sorted *first* by the length of String in reverse order, and *then* by value, so the order of these two sortings should be reversed.

For example, the following sorting:

```java
list.sort(
    Comparator.<String>comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)
              .thenComparing(String::length, Comparator.reverseOrder())
);
 
System.out.println(list);
```

provides the expected output:

```
[0001, 001, 01, 1, 002, 2, 3, 006, 06, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s reverse length order and not just lexical order?

Comment: @VGR, the initial implementation was in lexical order: `0001 < 001 < 002 < 1 < 2`